# Best way to solve a whack a mole game

Tags: python, complexity-theory

I have to make an algorithm which finds the shortest path to clear a board for my complexities class. The board(4*4) starts with a list of coordinates of popped up moles and the goal is to clear the board in the shortest amount of hits. Each hit will cause the mole and its vertically and horizontally adjacent moles change state (pop up if it was down and disappear if it was up).

At the moment I'm brute forcing every possible combination. That's 16 hits every iteration. Some boards take up to 10 moves to clear and thats 16^10 board possibilities. Is there any better way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Is the board initially set to some random configuration of popped-up moles?

Comment: yep. the config gets more difficult in the later algorithm tests.

Comment: [there's some interesting links here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_%28game%29) (essentially, Lights Out is the same game on a 5x5 grid).

Comment: Ah [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html) has some info as well.